# Logic to remove first n elements from an array

Tags: java, arrays

One of the methods that I need to write for an assignment is supposed to remove the first n elements from an array. However, I am not getting the correct output. I believe I'm having an off by one error, but I am not exactly sure how to fix it.

Solutions should try to maintain the format of the code as closely as possible.

```java
        for (int i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
            elementData[i] = elementData[i + 1];
            size--;
        }
```

What the code is saying is that, for every element n and below, replace it with whatever is in the index higher than it. Then reduce the size variable for every time that you do this, which should result in it looking like a remove operation when printed.

I expected the output of [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 7] to be [4, 7].

However, I got [7].

n is passed as 5 in the above case.

Comment: Assuming that `n == 5`?

Comment: Show the rest of the snippet please. That loop is not enough information.

Comment: *Solutions should try to maintain the format of the code as closely as possible.* - is that an order?

Comment: Whatever you are doing, you need to make it n-1 instead of n.

Comment: @BhanuPasrija I tried that, and the output was [4, 4].

Comment: @GhostCat A valid concern, I just wrote it that way since that's how it prints. It's an array list.

Comment: @David All I need to fix is that loop. It's the only part of the code that does anything related to this operation.

Comment: @achAmháin What I meant by this is that, since the assignment is for showing that I understand how ArrayLists work at the basic level, I'm required to use a for loop for this assignment.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an assignment question looking for an implementation, but anyone doing this in Java *should* use the provided APIs. For example:

```
public int[] trimArray(int[] source, int trimBy) {
  if (trimBy > source.length) return source;
  return Arrays.copyOfRange(source, trimBy, source.length);
}

trimArray(new int[]{0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 7}, 5) // -> [4, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this:

```
int[] result = new int[elementData.length - n];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = elementData[n + i];
}
```

Which is an extended form of this:

```
int[] result = new int[elementData.length - n];
System.arraycopy(elementData, n, result, 0, result.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter:

```
let a = [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 7]
```

you want to obtain `[4, 7]` removing `5` first elements so type

```
a = a.filter((_, i) => i >= 5)
```

Now

```
a = [4, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elementData = Arrays.copyOfRange( elementData, n, elementData.length ); // originalArray, startIndex, end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm supposed to use a for loop in this assignment.